# How to make my website made using jsp secure?

Tags: jsp, security, html

I have a **website made in jsp** which asks user to **authenticate by giving username and password**.once he authenticates he can do various things in his account.what I do is I check that user and password match exactly using database.But the problem is I authenticate only on 1st page and **if he enter the url of next page he can bypass the authentication** which is breach of security.I know its a very common problem but as I am new in this field I don't know how to correct this?

Comment: I believe that's one of only helpful (to the end user) uses of [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

Comment: @Okuma.Scott yhen I have to check for cookies on each page?

Answer (score 0):

in order of importance, the further down the more you can ignore it I guess :)

first of all, make sure the page the username/pass get filled into is using https.

secondly, ensure that the database does not store the password as plaintext, but encrypts it using a non-outdated algorithm. (crypt is not ok) when you check the given password, encrypt the pass entered by user, and compare the two encrypted forms to one another. they should be identical.

thirdly, use Session to store the users credentials (you can store under key "loggedInUser" value: the username. do not store password here :)

fourthly, in session try to store a few elements from the users request (ip address, user-agent) and when you check the user is already logged in, you also verify that the ip , user-agent still match. this is not a foolproof solution but it makes it harder to spoof session.

You can write a short piece of code which you can include (not copy paste, but use the include directive) in every page. if you make this the very first snippet that gets included before any others, you can make it direct to your login page. (just be careful if there were already newlines output beforehand, the redirect doesn't work if you've already written response. jsp is really not a brilliant place to do logic)

file: checkLoggedIn.jsp

```
<%
    String loggedInUser = session.getParameter( "loggedInUser" );
    if (loggedInUser == null) {
        response.sendRedirect("/login.jsp");
        return; // not 100% sure but think you need to have this one.
    }
%>
```

Comment: This answers my question partly what I want is user should not be able to access further url's without logging in.

Comment: if your login page does: session.setAttribute("loggedInUser", username) then the above snippet will not show any url to the user when they are not logged in. a non-logged in user will instead be redirected to login.jsp